# ScrollView swift compiler error

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift2

I keep getting this error:

> Ambiguous use of 'size

I looked everywhere and tried some tricks but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

```
import UIKit

class ScrollView: UIScrollView {
    var textField: UITextField!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0)

    }

    func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWasShown), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillBeHidden), name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
        let info: NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
        //HERE=>   let size = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)?.size  /* THIS IS THE LINE OF THE ERROR */
        let insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, size!.height, 0.0)

        self.contentInset = insets
        self.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets

        var rect = self.frame
        rect.size.height -= size!.height

    }

    func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification) {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        self.contentInset = insets
        self.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        self.textField = textField
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        self.textField = nil
    }

    /**
     * Called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
     */
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    /**
     * Called when the user click on the view (outside the UITextField).
     */
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

This is where I have the error. I use Swift 2.3 and Xcode 8.
I have tried to change my function but got even more errors.

Comment: this is the line of the error:                                                                             let size = info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)?.size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast the return of objectForKey. objectForKey returns type "Any" and you want method from CGRect class.

```
let size = (info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey) as! CGRect)?.size
```

Comment: cannot use optionnal chaining on non-optional value type 'CGRECT'